# vim: multiple replace operations

Tags: regex, vim, replace

I need to replace multiple patterns to get TeX notation in reports. I use vim for creating reports. There are many patterns to replace (about 100), for example,

```
%s/U_CC/$U_{CC}$/
%s/tplh/$t_{plh}$/
%s/U\(.*\)_\(.*\)V||\(.*\)$/$U_{\1}$|V|\3|$U_{CC}=\2 V$/
```

etc. Is there a way to speed up this work in vim, for example, by using some file with patterns and replacing strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function that chains all the substitutes (preceded with a `:silent!` to neutralize errors)., or you can put all your substitutions in a vim script (that you could put anywhere, or only in `~/.vim/macros/`  under `~/.vim/`), and source that script with `:so ~/.vim/macros/fix-my-report.vim` for instance.

Comment: Thanks! The variant with script is exactly what I need.